# How to check if a particular vector is pointing at X-Y plane or Y-Z plane

Tags: vector, coordinates, linear-algebra

[image]

As you can observe from the diagram,

Vector A is pointing at the Y-Z plane and Vector B is pointing at  X-Y plane.

Is this possible to find? Am I missing some logic or concept?

EDIT:
Suppose, Vector B moves forward in its local space, in this, it would be moving along the z-axis and the world x-coordinate wouldn't change, and for Vector A, it would be the other way round. Basically, I want to know, which world coordinate would change if the vector moves forward in the local space?

Comment: What constitutes as pointing? Does it have to be perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: Vector don't have position (they have direction and length). If we place them at the origin, they are all pointing away from it (well, except for the zero vector). *We could map a vector to the point it goes to if we place it at the origin, in which case it conceptually has position, but no direction or length. We could also map it to a plane, the one that is normal to the vector and passes through the point it goes to… But that is clearly not what is going on here.* By any chance do you mean rays (with an origin and a direction)?

Comment: Suppose, Vector B moves forward in its local space, in this, it would be moving along the z-axis and the world x-coordinate wouldn't change, and for Vector A, it would be the other way round. Basically, I want to know, which world coordinate would change if the vector moves forward in the local space?

Comment: If an object "moves foward" in the direction of the vector, then the position of the object changes in all non-zero components of the vector. If the vector has a zero component, then that coordinate does not change. Addendum: You mention local space, if you want to know about what coordinate in global does not change when you have your vector in local space, convert your vector to global space. Or viceversa.